# WCF try/catch block not catching exception + error occurence blocks webservice

Tags: c#, wcf, exception

I have a problem with my WCF. I have block of code in my webservice:

```
try { AtachThreadToClarion(); }
        catch (AccessViolationException) { this.log.Log("attach to clation exception: AccessViolationException"); }
        catch (SEHException) { this.log.Log("attach to clarion exception: SEHException"); }
        catch (Exception) { this.log.Log("attach to clarion exception: Exception"); }
```

When error occoures in this line of code, it's not catched at all. I have no idea what the error is, only that it blocks the webservice from receiving another requests for couple of minutes. 
Why I know this line is the issue here? I have log before and after the line in my code. While first log is saved to file, the one right after is not.

The webservice has ServiceBehaviour:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single,
                 ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Single)]
```

And my webservice works one request after another, in queue.
Any ideas how can I catch the exception, that's not even catched by Exception?
And/or how can I prevent my webservice from hanging after encountering it?

Comment: How do you know it's an exception? Sounds to me like the call is hanging until it time-outs...

Comment: It's possible. Anyhow, what can I do to prevent it from happening?

Comment: Enable [Tracing - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and find out what the problem really is.